# How to set a Failover Cluster between two Virtual Machines

Tags: cluster-computing, windows-server-2008, virtualization, windows-clustering

Does anyone know a link or a documentation to how set up a Failover Clustering between two Virtual machines or Hypevs?

Do I need to have vSphere Client and ESX/ESXi host? I have been searching for ever to find a clear documentation but with no result

The OS version is Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Xenserver also supports that but you need to pay to Citrix for that feature.